# Como crear Accesos personalizados para usuario en angular?

Tags: angular, adminlte

Estoy trabajando en la plantilla adminlte como tal soy un novato en Angular ,lo que quiero realizar es crear una directiva para usuario que solo tenga una opcion en su inicio de sesion y otra directiva para el administrador que  si tiene acceso a todas las opciones, me encuentro buscando pero no he visto aun nada congruente o que muestre el paso a paso para hacerlo, para poder realizarlo con instrucciones.

por el momento solo hay dos usuarios y dependiendo de su rol tienen accesos a ciertas opciones que se les permite.

Comment: Pues si no encuentras nada que haga exactamente lo que quieres y que puedas copiar y pegar, vas a tener que buscar por partes y adaptarlo tú mismo. No es tan difícil, si ya sabes hacer que tengan opciones diferentes, solo necesitas mirar cómo crear directivas, ver algún ejemplo y adaptarlo a tus necesidades. Al final, la mejor forma de aprender no es seguir tutoriales, si no *pelearte* con el código. Verás como unas cuantas semanas pegándote con eso y acabas sabiendo crear directivas de memoria :)

Comment: Por cierto, tu pregunta acabará cerrada porque no cumple las directrices de SO. Si quieres buscar material de soporte tienes google. Aquí trabajamos con problemas concretos, no damos clases particulares ni consejos sobre librerías, ni tutoriales, ni vídeos... Te recomiendo que, como te dije, hagas algo tú mismo y si tienes un problema concreto con alguna parte, seguro que podremos ayudarte. Para más info puedes leer [ask], hacer el [tour] y ante cualquier duda échale un ojo a [help] o pásate por el [chat], donde además solemos tratar temas que aquí en SO no son correctos :)

Comment: Hola!. Lo que quieres se denomina seguridad de la aplicación. Empieza por investigar algo como los JWT con angular. https://www.section.io/engineering-education/jwt-auth-angular/#:~:text=Your%20Angular%20app%20will%20communicate,granted%20based%20on%20its%20validity.